# Why class method doesn't get called?

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, methods

I am trying to call Class method "func" that supposed to print something but it never gets printed...No errors but just silence. Code bellow:

```
class AnyClass():
    atr1=0
    atr2='text'

    def func():
        print ('Ran Func')

a = AnyClass()
a.func
```

Comment: You're not calling it: `a.func()`

Comment: you get no errors because you are referencing a function that exists and has no errors, but you are not asking it to do anything by not calling it

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I also need to define if like: def func(self)

Answer (score 6):

`a.func` is just the name of a method object. You have to *call* it with `()`.

```
>>> a.func
<bound method AnyClass.func of <__main__.AnyClass object at 0x0000000003506240>>

>>> a.func()
Ran Func
```

Also note that you have to pass `self` to the method as the first argument when defining it unless the `@staticmethod` decorator is used.

```
def func(self):
        print ('Ran Func')
```

Answer (score 2):

`a.func` is just a reference to the function object.  To call it, you need to add parenthesis.

```
a.func()
```

Answer (score 0):

function should have parenthesis like a.func()